# Bash function argument parsing

Tags: bash

I want to have a function I can call from the command line that takes the following:

```
$ command_name /some/path/file.java
```

and turns into the following call:

```
command /some/path:file
```

So basically the part I'm having trouble with is substituting a `:` for the last `/` and stripping the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you question is.  Do you want a bash `function` or a bash `script`?  Splitting paths and files is easily done with the commands `basename` and `dirname`.

e.g.:

```
$ dirname /path/to/file.txt
/path/to

$ basename /path/to/file.txt
file.txt
```

But if you *must* do it with a regex, `sed` works well:

```
$ echo /path/to/file.txt | sed "s/.*\///"
file.txt

$ echo /path/to/file.txt | sed -r "s/(.+)\/.+/\1/"
/path/to
```

First a script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
COMMAND="/bin/echo"
JAVA="$1"
path=`dirname "$JAVA"`
file=`basename "$JAVA"`

exec "$COMMAND" "$path:$file"
```

And now a function:

```
fnA()
{ 
    COMMAND="$1"
    JAVA="$2"
    path=`dirname "$JAVA"`
    file=`basename "$JAVA"`

    exec "$COMMAND" "$path:$file"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the original path string,

```
/some/path/file.java
```

is passed to your script as $1, you get the modified string as

```
path_string_with_colon=$(dirname $1):$(basename $1 .java)
```